# Double slit experiment: effects of changing path difference between slits on diffreaction pattern

Tags: double-slit-experiment, interference

I know that interference pattern maxima occur due to path difference of integer number of wavelengths, causing constructive interference, and minima due non-integer number of wavelengths, causing destructive interference.

What happens to the pattern if the waves from slits have a path difference?  That is, two slits with path difference of 0.5 wavelength should arrive at the zeroth order maxima with destructive interference (non-integer wavelength). So will a central bright spot even exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already said, what has been the central interference maximum becomes a minimum at 180 degrees phase difference. Generally speaking, the whole interference pattern will just shift under the broader shape of the intensity envelope. If you go all the way from 0 to 180 to 360 degrees phase difference, the interference pattern will have cyclically returned to its original position in the end.

By the way, a simple way to achieve such a phase shift for electron double-slit diffraction is by the [Aharonov-Bohm effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect). A magnetic field confined to a cylinder which does not significantly overlap with the electron wave functions, does actually change the wave function's phase according to the magnetic vector potential, which is non-zero even in regions of space where the magnetic field vanishes. Hence, in quantum mechanics the vector potential becomes a part of observable physical reality, although it was apparently only a practical construction without deeper meaning in classical physics. I personally find the Aharonov-Bohm effect one of the most exciting aspects of quantum mechanics. And the theory around this is also responsible for some things concerning superconduction.

Comment: I see, this clarifies a lot

Answer (score 0):

For usual scenario, where initially there is no path difference, the bright spot is obtained at the central point on the screen because the path difference is **Zero**. In the diagram below $S_1P$ - $S_2P$ = $0$, so at point P central bright spot is obtianed.

[image]

Let's say we place glass slab in front of one of the slits, of such a thickness which can introduce a path difference of $\frac{\lambda}{2}$ [To make visualisation easy I did this].

[image]

So in this case the bright spot has shifted to point $P'$. Answer to your first question, "What happens to the pattern if the waves from slits have a path difference?", is that wave pattern just shifts its position. As path difference was introduced near slit $S_1$ so, $S_1P'$ - $S_2P'$ = 0, which means light rays from slit $S_2$ will have to travel longer to form bright spot.

From a question may arise, how much did the pattern shift? Not difficult to answer, find $PP'$. $P'$ is the position where the $1st$ minima would have formed if there was no initial path difference.